# Duplicated thymeleaf fragment after each loop

Tags: spring, html, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template that should render the contents of a map. Here is the template:

```
<div class="akuiteo list-group" data-th-each="akuiteo:${akuiteoMap.akuiteoMap}">
    <div data-th-replace="akuiteo::akuiteoView(${akuiteo.value},${akuiteo.key})"></div>
</div>
```

In the akuiteoView I have:

```
<button data-th-fragment="akuiteoView(commits,akuiteoNr)" class="akuiteo-file" data-th-each="commit:${commits}" data-th-id="${akuiteoNr}">
    <p data-th-text="${akuiteoNr}"></p>
    <div data-th-replace="commitDetails::commitView(${commit})">replace me</div>
</button>
```

The output I get is:

```
<body>
    <div class="akuiteo list-group">
         <button> content </button>
    </div>
    <div class="akuiteo list-group">
         <button> content </button>
         <button> content </button>
         <button> content </button>
         <button> content </button>
         <button> content </button>
         <button> content </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

The div with the akuiteo class is duplicated, moreover there is one button for each commit instead of one button for each akuiteo instance, I can't understand why this happens, the expected output is:

```
<body>
    <div class="akuiteo list-group">
         <button> content(a list of one commit) </button>
         <button> content(a list of 6 commits) </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Before I post my answer could you tell me why are you using `<button>`  element for rendering content? You shouldn't nest tags like `<div>` and `<p>` within button because it's syntactically incorrect, so your buttons should be replaced with `div`.

Comment: I have done that because of a bootstrap feature that enables multi-select lists with buttons, although it is possible that this can be avoided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of `data-th-each`. Thymeleaf iterates your map's entries and creates separate `div` for each entry. Then the same thing happens for buttons: thymeleaf render a new one for each commit. You should check out documentation explaining [iterating using th:each](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration).

To obtain expected output (1 div and 2 buttons) you should redesign your pages, e.g. like that:

```
<div class="akuiteo list-group">
    <button data-th-each="akuiteo:${akuiteoMap.akuiteoMap}">
        <span data-th-replace="akuiteo::akuiteoView(${akuiteo.value},${akuiteo.key})"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

and:

```
<span data-th-fragment="akuiteoView(commits,akuiteoNr)" data-th-each="commit:${commits}">
    <!-- here goes content of a single commit -->
<span>
```

By the way, a `<button>` tag shouldn't contain such elements like `<div>` or `<p>`. I don't know anything about commits' content but consider either redesigning `<button>` to `<div>` (to keep the commit structure containing `<p>` and `<div>`), or summarizing a commits from an `akuiteo` in textual form (to keep `<button>`).